# SOT23-5 Package vs SOT23-5L...Differences?

Tags: surface-mount, altium, packages, board

I'm designing a board which uses an LDO that comes in the SOT23-5 package. I have these parts in my possession, and on the part label (from Digikey) it displays that it is a SOT23-5, which makes sense. However, the part datasheet lists it as a SOT23-5 **L**, and I can't find **any** documentation on the difference between the "standard" package and the L suffix. I'm thinking that the L might be for low profile, like in LQFP packages, but for all I know, there isn't any difference, and it's just a manufacturer anomaly.

I'm only concerned because in Altium, it appears that there are two distinct footprints for the two. Is the "L" just the same size package with larger pads (in Altium), or is there some other minute difference between the two?

[This](http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/LD2981ABM33TR/497-1521-1-ND/592041) is the part I'm using, and [here is the datasheet](http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00001635.pdf).

Comment: The 'safe' way to resolve this issue would be looking at the measurements page of the datasheet and comparing the Altium model against those measurements.

Comment: "No, ma'am, this is [Area 51-*A*](http://simpsonswiki.net/wiki/Area_51-A)"

Comment: <strike>Papers</strike> Part number, Please.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>I believe the difference is the same as Sot23-5+, in that the 6th pin (Sot-23 can accommodate 6 regular pins) is present, but unused. Regular Sot23-5 has the 6th pin missing.</strike>

Based on looking at some other ST datasheets, Sot23-5 and Sot23-5l are used interchangeably.
http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00176077.pdf
http://www.st.com/web/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00079372.pdf

The measurements are exactly the same in any case.

Also, you should always add the part number (AND manufacturer in this specific case) to the question.

Comment: You say jump, I say how high.....Data sheet and part link added.